# Auto Increment a value using a MySQL trigger

Tags: mysql

I've been trying to set up an auto increment in a table based upon the insertion of data into one of my tables,

Befor this gets flagged as a duplicate, I've already looked at other questions and I think my main issue is misunderstanding of the syntax regarding a trigger,specifically the line:

```
WHERE ID = NEW.ID;
```

MySQL Block:

```
CREATE TABLE Members(
    ID  INT  UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE,
    FIRST_NAME  TEXT(16),
    LAST_NAME  TEXT(16),
    TITLE  TEXT(7), /** 7 CHARS for  'Student'*/
    INSTITUTION  VARCHAR(2048),
    No_Publications INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(ID)
  );
CREATE TABLE Papers(
    ISBN  INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    Title  TEXT(4),
    Publish_Date  DATE NOT NULL,
    Topic  TEXT(128),
    PRIMARY KEY(ISBN)
  );
  CREATE TABLE Publications(
    Researcher_ID  INT  UNSIGNED NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    ISBN  INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    PRIMARY KEY (Researcher_ID, ISBN),
    FOREIGN KEY(Researcher_ID) REFERENCES Members(ID) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY(ISBN) REFERENCES Papers(ISBN) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE /**Used in
    many to many relations*/
  );

  CREATE TRIGGER New_Publication AFTER INSERT ON Publications
  FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
  UPDATE Members SET No_Publications = No_Publications + 1 WHERE ID = NEW.ID;
  END;
```

EDIT:
Upon insertion into the Publications table, I want the No_Publication column in the Members table to increment by one

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: @digital.aaron how can i formulate a trigger that actually works because this one isnt for some reason

Comment: Then you should update your post with your actual question, sample data, expected results, and actual results.

Comment: @digital.aaron done

Answer (score 0):

There is no `id` field in the `publications` table, so there cannot be any `NEW.ID`. You must have received an unknown field error in mysql. The create table statement for `publications` contains the clue as to what field to use in the update:

```
FOREIGN KEY(Researcher_ID) REFERENCES Members(ID)
```

Therefore the update should look like:

```
UPDATE Members SET No_Publications = No_Publications + 1 WHERE ID = NEW.Researcher_ID
```

Also, there is no need for `begin ... end`, since the trigger body consists of a single sql statement:

```
CREATE TRIGGER New_Publication AFTER INSERT ON Publications
  FOR EACH ROW
  UPDATE Members SET No_Publications = No_Publications + 1 WHERE ID = NEW.Researcher_ID;
```